# Only allow input of integers with java scanner

Tags: java

I recently asked about a question about this code, but I had another. I want to setup the scanner to only accept integers, because when I enter a letter in testing, I get this error:

```
 java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at RockPaperScissorsTest.main(RockPaperScissorsTest.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

So, what can I do to only allow  integers in the scanner? So if you typed one, it would not show anything in the scanner box. Thanks for the help! Below is the entire program.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class RockPaperScissorsTest {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
    int P1;
    int P2;
    do {
        System.out.println("Player 1, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
        P1 = input.nextInt();
    } while (P1 != 1 && P1 != 2 && P1 != 3);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    do {
        System.out.println("Player 2, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
        P2 = input.nextInt();
    } while (P2 != 1 && P2 != 2 && P2 != 3);
    if (P1 == 1 & P2 == 1)
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    if (P1 == 1 & P2 == 2)
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
    if (P1 == 1 & P2 == 3)
        System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
    if (P1 == 2 & P2 == 1)
        System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
    if (P1 == 2 & P2 == 2)
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    if (P1 == 2 & P2 == 3)
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
    if (P1 == 3 & P2 == 1)
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
    if (P1 == 3 & P2 == 2)
        System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
    if (P1 == 3 & P2 == 3)
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
}
```

}

Comment: you could simplify your code a  lot. `if ((P1 - P2) == 0)) { it's a tie }`.

Comment: You could either take a `char` as input and manually check the value, or use a `try`/`catch` block to catch the error.

Comment: see [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt())

Comment: Building off of @MarcB, you can use some modular arithmetic to get the winner, `int winner=(P1-P2+3)%3`. if winner is 1, player 1 wins; if winner is 2, player 2 wins; else if winner is 0 it is a tie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` to see if an integer can be read; note that you will have to skip the token with `next()` if it is not an integer so you don't get "stuck".
- Read the token as a string and use `Integer.parseInt()`, ignoring tokens that cannot be parsed as an integer.

Comment: Can you explain the Scanner.hasNextInt() method for my case? I've tried for half an hour but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think a solution is to use a while block, and test until the input is an Integer, like this:

```
int choice;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "a";
boolean notAnInteger = true;
while(notAnInteger){
     input = sc.next();
     try{
         choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
         notAnInteger = false;
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Not an integer");
     }

}
```

I haven't tested this but I think it should work ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
     boolean testing = false;
     String pos = "";
     while(true)
     {
     testing = false;   
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the integer value.... ");
     pos = sc.next();
     for(int i=0; i<pos.length();i++)
     {
         if(!Character.isDigit(pos.charAt(i)))
             testing = true;
     }
     if(testing == true)
     {
         System.out.print("Enter only numbers..   ");
         continue;
     }

     else
     {
         int key = Integer.parseInt(pos);
         // Your code here....
         break;
     }
```

Comment: You can use this method...This will repeatedly asks for integer input until it gets the integer input...

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here

1. You could surround your input.nextInt() inside a try/catch block and catch the InputMismatchException. You could then prompt them again or handle this however you like.

   ```
   try {
      P1 = input.nextInt();
   } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      //Handle how you choose.
   }
   ```
2. [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has a hasNextInt() method which will evaluate to true if the next token is an int.

   ```
   if(input.hasNextInt()){
      P1 = input.nextInt();
   } else {
      //Handle how you choose. 
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the second option? This is essentially what I want, without the else. I believe the program will already loop if the statement is returned without an integer that is 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: hasNextInt() checks to see if the next token is an int. As an example, if the user enters 'Hello' then this will fail because that is clearly not an int. However, if they enter a value such as '5' this will pass the if block and grab the integer value. If they don't pass an integer you still need to move the Scanner along by adding something like input.next() in the above else. You always need to remember to grab the input the user gives you, even if its not an int. Also, I put a link on Scanner above which will have more information about the hasNextInt() method.