# User input only numbers, not text in Java

Tags: java, numbers, user-input

I am working on a recipe manager project in Java where I have the user input: name of the ingredient, calories per cup of the ingredient, cups of the ingredient, and finally the program will then calculate the total of calories total.

My issue is that if a user inputs a letter or symbol, then the program crashes. I would like to know how I can fix that. Any help would be great!

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String nameOfIngredient = "";
   float numberCups = 0;
   int numberCaloriesPerCup = 0;
   double totalCalories = 0.0;

   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ingredient: ");
   nameOfIngredient = scnr.next();

   System.out.println("Please enter the number of cups of " + nameOfIngredient + " we'll need: ");
   numberCups = scnr.nextFloat();


   System.out.println("Please enter the name of calories per cup: ");
   numberCaloriesPerCup = scnr.nextInt();

   totalCalories = numberCups * numberCaloriesPerCup;

   System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + numberCups + " cups and has " + totalCalories + " calories.");

}
```

}

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Wrap your code with try and catch block to handle NumberFormatException, it will help.

Answer (score 3):

Though your program works for valid inputs, you can make it robust by checking for invalid ones like non-numbers where a number is expected. Your program crashes for a reason: when a user inputs a string, not a number, in this line:

```
numberCups = scnr.nextFloat();
```

... then the method `nextFloat()` will raise an *exception*, a `NumberFormatException` to be precise. The Java interpreter cannot handle this exception - it doesn't know what to do when this (valid) situation arises. There is something you can do about that:

```
do {
  bool validInput = true;
  try {
    numberCups = scnr.nextFloat();
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    validInput = false;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
  }
} while(!validInput);
```

Now, Java will `try` to execute `nextFloat`, and if it fails with a `NumberFormatException`, it executes the `catch` block. This gives you a chance to tell the user that their input was wrong. I've put everything in a loop so that when the exception arises, the loop simply runs again until a valid number is input. Note that if the exception does not arise, then the `catch` block is never executed.

It is good practice to wrap code where an expected error may occur in such a `try` block in order to handle the situation without unnecessarily crashing the program. Note that there are [many types of Exceptions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-exception-in-java-with-examples/). You should catch the one you expect may happen.

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out answer Alexander! It is super appreciated, especially since I am such a beginner in writing code. I will try what you said.

Answer (score 2):

Ref : [Only allow input of integers with java scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285080/10240461)

```
 boolean testing = false;
 String pos = "";
 while(true)
 {
 testing = false;   
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter the integer value.... ");
 pos = sc.next();
 for(int i=0; i<pos.length();i++)
 {
     if(!Character.isDigit(pos.charAt(i)))
         testing = true;
 }
 if(testing == true)
 {
     System.out.print("Enter only numbers..   ");
     continue;
 }

 else
 {
     int key = Integer.parseInt(pos);
     // Your code here....
     break;
 }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed answer Ashvin. Really appreciate it! The StackOverflow community is amazing!

Comment: Welcome... @Joao

Answer (score 1):

You could change `nextFloat()` and `nextInt()` for `nextLine()`, then try to convert them to `Integer` or `Float` inside a try-catch block using `Integer.parseInt()` and `Float.parseFloat()`.

Comment: Thank you ayrton! Will try that

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do is as @ayrton said, use `scnr.nextLine()` instead of `next()` or `nextFloat()`. you can always use the `Integer.parseInt()` method from Integer class to convert the string into a Number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Adithya! I will be playing around with my code and do as you and ayrton have suggested.